# Magento: Flush widget from block / fullpage cache if widget parameters change

Tags: php, magento, caching

We have a widget on the start page of our shop.

The shop uses FPC and block cache.

How can we update the widget contents if the admin changes the widget settings in the backend?

Is it possible to use the Widget's configuration data in the CacheKey?

Or do we have to set the cache lifetime very small?

EDIT: My own answer uses the cache lifetime. 
What would be the way to pointedly clean the cached blocks from FPC only when the widget instance is edited?

Comment: Are you talking about a widget instance (Admin > CMS > Widgets) or about embedded widgets in CMS blocks and/or pages (Admin > CMS > Pages or Static Blocks)?

Comment: About a Widget instance in "Admin > CMS > Widgets"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## EE Full Page Cache and Widget Instances Caching

### (no rewrites, unlimited cache life time)

### Overview

The **first step** is to create the frontend widget itself, but providing some additional info the full page cache can use.
The **second step** is to handle the hole punching in the full page cache for the widget.
The **third step** is to automatically clean the widget cache only for this widget if it is changed in the admin area.

### Step one: create the widget

First, create the *etc/widget.xml* file for your module:

```
<widgets>
    <netzarbeiter_test type="netzarbeiter_test/widget_test">
        <name>FPC Holepunch Cache Test</name>
        <description>Dummy test widget</description>
        <parameters>
            <!-- This is the important parameter here: -->
            <unique_id>
                <required>1</required>
            </unique_id>
            <example_text>
                <visible>1</visible>
                <label>Example Text Parameter</label>
                <type>text</type>
            </example_text>
        </parameters>
    </netzarbeiter_test>
</widgets>
```

Notice the parameter `<unique_id>`. We don't supply a input type or value, it will be automatically filled with a generated value by the `Mage_Widget_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Options::_addField()` method:

```
    // Excerpt from Mage_Widget_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Options::_addField()

    if ($values = $this->getWidgetValues()) {
        $data['value'] = (isset($values[$fieldName]) ? $values[$fieldName] : '');
    }
    else {
        $data['value'] = $parameter->getValue();
        //prepare unique id value
        if ($fieldName == 'unique_id' && $data['value'] == '') {
            $data['value'] = md5(microtime(1));
        }
    }
```

Because of this little gem we **do not** have to rewrite the `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance` class to inject the widget id into the generated layout xml.

Next, create the widget class itself. This is just a regular block instance implementing the `Mage_Widget_Block_Interface` interface, except that the `unique_id` is used in the `cacheKeyInfo` method.

```
class Netzarbeiter_Test_Block_Widget_Test
    extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
    implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        $info = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
        if ($id = $this->getData('unique_id')) {
            // Because the array key is a string, it will be added to the FPC placeholder
            // parameters. That is how the FPC container can access it (see below).
            $info['unique_id'] =  (string) $id;
        }
        return $info;
    }

    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        // The FPC was completely cleared (or not created yet), 
        // recreate the widget parameter cache
        if (! $this->getFullPageCacheEnvironment() && $this->getUniqueId()) {
            $id = Netzarbeiter_Test_Model_Fpc_Container_Widget_Test::CACHE_PREFIX . $this->getUniqueId() . '_params';
            Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->save(serialize($this->getData()), $id);
        }
        // Just some dummy output to display the text parameter and the render time
        $time = now();
        $textParam = $this->escapeHtml($this->getExampleText());
        return <<<EOF
<p><b>Render Time:</b> {$time}<br/>
<b>Example Text:</b> {$textParam}<br/></p>
EOF;
    }
}
```

When we add a widget instance through the admin interface now, the `unique_id` parameter specified in *widget.xml* the  will be added to the layout xml (formatting added for readability:

```
SELECT layout_update_id, handle, xml FROM core_layout_update;
+------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| layout_update_id | handle                   | xml                                                                                                |
+------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|               17 | catalog_category_layered | <reference name="left">
|                  |                          |     <block type="netzarbeiter_test/widget_test" name="2a3b55e13549e176709fc6c67a4a7bd8">
|                  |                          |         <action method="setData">
|                  |                          |             <name>unique_id</name>
|                  |                          |             <value>7fa2574145ef204fb6d179cfc604ac76</value>
|                  |                          |         </action>
|                  |                          |         <action method="setData">
|                  |                          |             <name>example_text</name>
|                  |                          |             <value>This is a String!</value>
|                  |                          |         </action>
|                  |                          |     </block>
|                  |                          | </reference>
+------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This means, whenever the block instance is created through the layout xml rendering, the `unique_id` parameter will be known on the block object.

### Step two: full page cache hole punching

Add the *etc/cache.xml* file:

```
<config>
    <placeholders>
        <cms_block_widget>
            <block>netzarbeiter_test/widget_test</block>
            <placeholder>WIDGET_FPC_TEST</placeholder>
            <container>Netzarbeiter_Test_Model_Fpc_Container_Widget_Test</container>
        </cms_block_widget>
    </placeholders>
</config>
```

Next, create the container class:

```
class Netzarbeiter_Test_Model_Fpc_Container_Widget_Test
    extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract
{
    const CACHE_PREFIX = 'TEST_WIDGET_';

    protected function _getCacheId()
    {
        return self::CACHE_PREFIX . $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('unique_id');
    }

    protected function _renderBlock()
    {
        $block = $this->_getPlaceHolderBlock();
        // Set any parameters from the placeholder on the block as needed.
        // See observer below where the current parameters are cached.
        $id = $this->_getCacheId() . '_params';
        if ($parameters = Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->load($id)) {
            $block->addData(unserialize($parameters));
            // Set environment information on block (used in _toHtml,
            // the params cache is recreated when not set)
            $block->setFullPageCacheEnvironment(true);
        }
        Mage::dispatchEvent('render_block', array('block' => $block, 'placeholder' => $this->_placeholder));
        return $block->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Thats all that is needed to make our widget a dynamic block within fully cached pages. But so far, the widget block is cached indefinitely. We still need to take care of the cache refresh.

### Step three: cache refresh on widget save

Use an event observer for the automatic `*_save_commit_after` event all Magento models provide specific to widget instances. It is triggered every time a widget instance is saved in the admin interface.

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <widget_widget_instance_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <netzarbeiter_test>
                    <model>netzarbeiter_test/observer</model>
                    <method>widgetWidgetInstanceSaveCommitAfter</method>
                </netzarbeiter_test>
            </observers>
        </widget_widget_instance_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

The last piece of the puzzle is the observer method:

```
public function widgetWidgetInstanceSaveCommitAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var $widget Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance */
    $widget = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    $parameters = $widget->getWidgetParameters();
    $uniqueId = isset($parameters['unique_id']) ? $parameters['unique_id'] : '';
    if (strlen($uniqueId)) {
        $id = Netzarbeiter_Test_Model_Fpc_Container_Widget_Test::CACHE_PREFIX . $uniqueId;
        Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->remove($id);
        $id = Netzarbeiter_Test_Model_Fpc_Container_Widget_Test::CACHE_PREFIX . $uniqueId . '_params';
        Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->save(serialize($parameters), $id);
    }
}
```

### Summary

Now the instance on the frontend will automatically be updated every time it is saved, even with an activated full page cache. At all other times the dynamic block will be fetched from the cache.

EDIT: Added the cached widget parameters example to the code because, as Alex pointed out in the comments below, the placeholder arguments won't be refreshed as long as the FPC entry exists.
Using the cache to pass the widget parameters to the block avoids rewriting it widget instance model and loading the widget instance when the block is rendered dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, Vinai! I am wondering when unique_id is generated. Only when I first add the widget or everytime I change something? I guess it is persistent, because otherwise the $cache->remove() would not work. I think I would still need to load the widget instance in the _renderBlock function like I did in my answer, if the widget has parameters that can change?

Comment: The `unique_id` parameter value is only generated once, then it persists, as seen in the code snipplet I included. If you don't want to load the `widget/widget_instance` in `_renderBlock`, you can pass all configured parameters to the cache container, for example through the `cache_key_info` array (like the `unique_id`). Since the block isn't cached in the regular Magento BLOCK_HTML cache, that would usually have no adverse side effects.

Comment: Okay - then I think I need to re-load the widget info in `_renderBlock` (see my answer). I tried before passing the parameters in the `cache_key_info` array - but this information is contained in the caches page and thus will not change if the change the widget parameters.

Comment: To elaborate a bit further: If the Full Page Cache is enabled, the regular BLOCK_HTML cache is deactivated (see `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer::processPreDispatch()`, `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->banUse(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::CACHE_GROUP);`

Comment: Good to know, I edited my answer. But _renderBlock is for the Fullpage Cache - isn't it? And if I do not reload the widget parameters, the old ones would be used?

Comment: So I think I need to reload the widget's parameters using the widget ID as I did in my answer.

Comment: Good point Alex. I think I would add another cache record to pass in the widget parameters to the block instance, to avoid having to rewrite `Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance`.

Comment: I do not get this one. What do you mean by cache record exactly?

Comment: Added an example parameter that is passed through the cache to the block to the answer.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I think I have to save the widget again now after I cleared the cache???

Comment: Clearing the FCP cache via the admin only removes all entries with the FPC cache tag. The widget params are only part of the MAGE cache segment. So even when the FPC is cleared via the admin, the widget params cache records persist. If you clear the FPC cache completely (`rm -rf /var/full_page_cache` or similar) then yes, you would have to re-save the widget. I'll readily this is no bullet proof workaround, but it could be made somewhat more robust probably without to much effort. In practice it works rather well.

Comment: But I do the `rm -rf cache` all the time. I think removing the cache should not influence the system. From my point of view we can not use the cache to store data that is not automatically restored after the cache storage was purged.

Comment: I added 1 line to the containers `_renderBlock()` method and 4 to the blocks `_toHtml()` method to automatically recreate the parameter cache entry if the complete cache is removed. Now even if the complete cache is purged, passing the parameters via the cache works.

Comment: You sure don't give it away easily ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the method `getCacheKeyInfo` and use some block specific values to generate a unique hash.

In Magento EE you can see this i.e. in block `Enterprise_Banner_Block_Widget_Banner`

Comment: `getCacheKeyInfo` is not executed on the second page load.

Comment: So, as far as I understand it, we can not use `getCacheKeyInfo` to transmit dynamic data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only possibility is to do this via the cache_lifetime parameter.
So we set this to around 30 seconds and every 30 seconds the widget is refreshed based on the current configuration.

I did not find a solution to remove the item from the cache immediately just when the parameters change.

This is what I did:

1. First of all, the widget block needs to know the ID of the widget instance. In order to do so I had to rewrite Mage_Widget_Model_Widget_Instance::generateLayoutUpdateXml in my one module:

   ```
   public function generateLayoutUpdateXml($blockReference, $templatePath = '')
   {
       $xml = parent::generateLayoutUpdateXml($blockReference, $templatePath);
       $injectXml = '<action method="setData"><name>widget_instance_id</name><value>' .     
             $this->getId() . '</value></action>';
       $xml = str_replace('</block>', $injectXml . '</block>', $xml);
       return $xml;
   }
   ```
2. <s>In my widget block, I set the cachelifetime very small to avoid double caching:</s> EDIT: not needed as the FPC disabled the block cache

   ```
   public function getCacheLifetime()
   {
       return 1;
   }
   ```
3. Include the current template and **widget instance id** in the cache info. I found out that those array entries with a string-key are mapped to the attributes in the FPC placeholder:

   ```
   public function getCacheKeyInfo()
   {
       $instanceId = $this->getWidgetInstanceId();

       return array(
           'MYBOX',
           Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
           (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),
           Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
           Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
           'widget_instance_id' => $instanceId,
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
       );
   }
   ```
4. Now we have to create an own FPC placeholder for this widgets. This placeholder loads the current configuration of the widget instance and renders the widget

   ```
   class MyCompany_PageCache_Model_Container_WidgetInstance
       extends Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Container_Abstract
   {
       protected function _renderBlock()
       {
           $instanceId = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('widget_instance_id');
           $widgetInstance = Mage::getModel('widget/widget_instance')->load($instanceId);
           if($widgetInstance->getId()) {
               Mage::logException( new Exception('Widget Instance '.$instanceId.' not         found') );
           }
           $data = $widgetInstance->getWidgetParameters();

           $block = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('block');

           $name = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('name');
           $template = $this->_placeholder->getAttribute('template');

           $block = new $block;
           $block->setTemplate($template);
           if ($name !== null) {
               $block->setNameInLayout($name);
           }
           $block->setLayout(Mage::app()->getLayout());
           $block->setData($data);


           return $block->toHtml();
       }
       }
   ```
5. We have to add the cache.xml configuration for this placeholder:

   ```
   <mycompany_mybox>
       <block>mycompany_mybox/widget</block>
       <placeholder>MYCOMPANY_MYBOX_WIDGET</placeholder>
       <container>MyCompany_PageCache_Model_Container_WidgetInstance</container>
       <cache_lifetime>30</cache_lifetime>
   </mycompany_mybox>
   ```
6. Finally the widget has to be saved once in the backend so that the new layout xml is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

1. Override `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Validator` in your module.
2. Add `Mage_Widget_Block_Interface` to the `protected $_dataChangeDependency` array in this class.
3. Rewrite `protected function _getObjectClasses($object)` in next way:

---

```
/**
 * Get list of all classes related with object instance
 *
 * @param $object
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getObjectClasses($object)
{
    $classes = array();
    if (is_object($object)) {
        $classes[] = get_class($object);
        $classes = array_merge($classes, class_implements($object), class_parents    ($object));
    }
    return $classes;
}
```